# How can I authorize with one address and pull data with another in Power BI?

Tags: database, powerbi

I'm trying to connect to a web service.

The only issue is that to authorize the url is:

```
  https://fake.com/ws/auth/login?usr_id=test&password=test
```

While to get the actual json the url is:

```
  https://fake.com/ws/cws/jobs/
```

I've tried adding the authorization to the json url but that doesn't work, i've also tried using the credentials with the Basic option on the Access Web Content screen, and so far no dice.

Wondering if anyone would know how to make this work.

Comment: Regarding `?usr_id=test&password=test`. It's a security flaw to allow to put secrets in URL. This should be rather done with a post request.

Comment: And I believe without knowing what type of authorization fake.com actually requires, all you are left with is guessing.